# util.inspect() result on one line

Tags: node.js

I use  `util.inspect({})` frequently, but sometimes the results are multiline (well, more often than not really).

Is there a way to tell `util.inspect()` to use no newlines (put everything one line)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use one of [util.inspect options](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):

```
util.inspect(object, {breakLength: Infinity});
```

This will prevent all linebreaks:

> breakLength  The length at which an object's keys are split across multiple lines. Set to Infinity to format an object as a single line. Default: 60 for legacy compatibility.

Comment: `Infinity - 1` is also sufficient

Comment: @Paulpro what's the point in that? (I'm really just trying to understand ... not sure what good would come of that, especially since infinity minus one is... infinity)

Comment: @LFLFM I was just trying to be funny. `Infinity - 1 === Infinity`, so the code would function identically.

Comment: For some reason in node v14. This isn't working for array of size more than 5. It'll still split into multiple lines.